# Django - Is it possible to access some content of one function from another function?

Tags: python, django

I have two functions in one of my Django-based projects, under the **views.py** file. Where the first function generates a view page and the second function is just returns some response based on jQuery request. Here's how they look like:

**First function that renders a show page:**

```
@login_required()
def watchlist_details(request, iid):
    ... ... ...
    ... ... ...
    contracts = dict(enumerate(x.rstrip() for x in symbols))
    automate = Automate()
    automate.init_symbol(contracts)
    automate.live_stream()
    ... ... ...
    ... ... ...
    return render(request, 'watchlist_show.html')
```

**Second function that will return some response on a jQuery call:**

```
def streaming_response(request):
    automate = Automate() #  need to replace this with: automate = automate_of_first_function
    result = automate.get_stream_result()
    json_result = json.dumps(result)
    return json_result
```

Here the problem is in the second function is, I reinitialize `automate` which does not have any content to generate a response. So, I need to access the method `automate` instance that is initialized in the `watchlist_details` function.

As I follow function-based views in my Django apps rather than class-based views so there is no way to create a global/common variable. And I think Django does not allow the creation of more than one method in class-based views (and it is also a confusing concept for me).

So my question, is it possible to access the `automate` instance (that is initialized in the first function) from the second function? If yes, then how can I access it?

Thanks

Comment: You need to fundamentally understand that each HTTP request is independent and stateless. It’s not about functions or classes, it’s that the second request coming in has nothing to do with any previous request and the server doesn’t remember anything. Always consider that multiple users may be using your server simultaneously, and/or that you may be running two or more servers simultaneously and it’s random which one serves the request. You only have the information contained within the request itself and need to derive all necessary information from that.

Answer (score 0):

Extract shared logic to new method

```
def init_automate():
    contracts = dict(enumerate(x.rstrip() for x in symbols))
    automate = Automate()
    automate.init_symbol(contracts)
    automate.live_stream()
    return automate

def watchlist_details(request, iid):
    ...
    automate = init_automate()
    ...

def streaming_response(request):
    ...
    automate = init_automate()
    ...
```

maybe use cache or instance-level global variable for keeping initialized `automate` object.